# setting Stack Layout Visibility to false at start

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am stuck with a problem.
I am having a stack layout which should be displayed according to a data loaded from api request
I have bound isVisible to the api Response it is working good but the problem is that the loading takes minute time the problem is once page opened thestack layout remains visible a bit time and then visibility is  changed according to the response

**here is my XAML**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="FailureResult" IsVisible="{Binding PlaceDetails.isErrorScreen,Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}">
       <Label Text="{StaticResource GooglePlaceNotFound}" />
</StackLayout>
```

please help me for the above situation. I want the stack layout visibility to false intially and then based on the response change the visbility
Thanks in advance

Comment: you might be better off doing this in code instead of binding

Comment: Why not use a loading screen until you fetch all the data ? Else do what @Jason said, and start with the StackLayout false at first

Comment: @ajit if you want to use binding,create one bool property as false, then you get all data by api, change this bool property as true, don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify changed.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT thanks  i have done it by bindind to property which is initially set as false and then assigning the property with value once the api call is completed

Comment: @ajit It seems that you have solved your issue now, please post one reply , and mark your reply as answer, it is may be helpful to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it by binding with a property until the api request is completed. The bound property is initially set as false. Once the api request is completed the the bound property is changed according to the api result.

xaml

```
<StackLayout x:Name="FailureResult" IsVisible="{Binding ErrorVisibility }">
    <Label Text="{StaticResource GooglePlaceNotFound}" />
</StackLayout>
```

ViewModel

```
 private bool _errorVisibility = false;
        public bool ErrorVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return this._errorVisibility;
            }
            set
            {
                this._errorVisibility = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

APImethod()
{
ErrorVisibility = PlaceDetails.isErrorScreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate Property for visibility of the StackLayout.

```
public bool StackLayoutIsVisible => PlaceDetails != null;
```

Then once the api call is done raise your on property changed method.

```
PlaceDetails = response;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StackLayoutIsVisible));
```

Comment: Thanks i have achieved it by binding with a property untill the api request is completed